# Fuzzy match within the same column - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Problem: I have records in one column, eg. Bulambuli and Bulambuli district which are essentially the same.

Solution: I was trying to search a sort of fuzzy match within the same column and found -[Pandas replace strings with fuzzy match in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58904764/pandas-replace-strings-with-fuzzy-match-in-the-same-column):

```
import difflib 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'district' : pd.Series(['Bulambuli', 'Kampla', 'Uttah' ,'Bulambuli district'])})
names = df['district']
def fuzzy_replace(x, names):
    aliases = difflib.get_close_matches(x, names)
    closest = pd.Series(aliases).mode()
    closest = aliases[0] if closest.empty else closest[0]
    df['district'].replace(aliases, closest, True)
df["district"].apply(lambda x: fuzzy_replace(x, df['district']))
```

The result:
[image]

Have you had a similar problem? How would you suggest me to approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'district' : pd.Series(['Bulambuli', 'Kampla', 'Uttah', 'Bulambuli district'])})
df
    district
0   Bulambuli
1   Kampla
2   Uttah
3   Bulambuli district
```

Just return the closest:

```
def fuzzy_replace(x, names):
    aliases = difflib.get_close_matches(x, names)
    closest = pd.Series(aliases).mode()
    closest = aliases[0] if closest.empty else closest[0]
    return closest

df["district"].apply(lambda x: fuzzy_replace(x, df['district']))
```

Output:

```
0    Bulambuli
1       Kampla
2        Uttah
3    Bulambuli
```

The string `Bulambuli` is returned by the function since it is the most similar value to `Bulambuli district` in the df.

Comment: Thank you for the response. And then, the next step is to count duplicates?

Comment: I thought you just wanted to replace the strings in district column with the closest match. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to keep only one occurence of Bulambuli and discard the other?

Comment: I actually wanted to find duplicates.

Comment: 1. duplicated() does the exact match; 2. no, the results don't seem to make sense, still checking.

Comment: What the code is doing is the follow: for each row (let's call it x) in the df, the function fuzzy_replace is looking for the closest match with x among all the values in the column district. Then that match is returned. So for instance, when x='Bulambuli district', the function finds that Bulambuli is the closest, and returns it. That's why in row 3 in the updated district column of df there is now only Bulambuli.

Comment: No, it is too broad score for: Kabaale vs. Wanale it considered the same. I changed to lst = [] for l in df_list:
    for word in df_list:
        txt = "score for: " + l + " vs. " + word + " = " + str(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, l, word).ratio())
        ls.append(txt)

Comment: It seems that whatever is after 60% is too broad

Comment: If you set a cutoff of 0.65 kabaale and Wanale are not considered the same:  `difflib.get_close_matches(x, names, cutoff=0.65)`